middleware for react-router-dom
I need to save the history of the user's movement on the site.
This my code:
const MyReactComponent = lazy(() =>
  import('./my_react-component.ui').then((module) => ({ default: module.MyReactComponent })),
)

function withSuspense<Props extends object>(
  component: ComponentType<Props>,
  suspenseProps: SuspenseProps & {
    FallbackComponent?: ComponentType
  },
) {
  const Wrapped = forwardRef<ComponentType<Props>, Props>(
    (props: Props, ref: ForwardedRef<ComponentType<Props>>) =>
      createElement(
        Suspense,
        {
          fallback:
            suspenseProps.fallback ||
            (suspenseProps.FallbackComponent &&
              createElement(suspenseProps.FallbackComponent)),
        },
        createElement(component, { ...props, ref }),
      ),
  );

  const name = component.displayName || component.name || 'Unknown';
  Wrapped.displayName = `withSuspense(${name})`;

  return Wrapped;
}

const enhance = compose((component) =>
    withSuspense(component, {
    fallback: (
      <Loader "/>
    ),
  }),
);

export const PageRoute1: RouteObject = {
  path: 'other-path/page',
  element: createElement(enhance(MyReactComponent)),
}

const browserRouter = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    errorElement: <BubbleError />,
    children: [
      {
        element: createElement(enhance(GenericLayout)),
        children: [PageRoute1, PageRoute2],
      },
      {
        element: createElement(enhance(EmptyLayout)),
        children: [page404Route],
      },
      {
        loader: async () => redirect(PATH_KEYS.page404),
        path: '*',
      },
    ],
  }
])

I find library https://github.com/verolisoft/react-router-dom-middleware but she has few stars and downloads. And for sure, react-router-dom allows you to implement this without third-party libraries. How do I write middleware?

Middleware for what exactly? Whatever the middleware is for will/should likely include documentation how to create custom middleware for it. What exactly are you trying to do? Please [edit] to clarify the question and expectations.

As I wrote above: I need to save the history of the user's movement on the site

The "I need to save the history of the user's movement on the site" part was already clear enough. What does that have to do with "middleware for react-outer-dom" or "How do I write middleware?" What do you need a middleware for? What unit of code do you have that accepts/consumes middleware? React-Router-DOM doesn't have any middleware.

I didn't understand

Sorry, can you clarify what you did not understand?

I didn't understand what you didn't understand.

I don't understand what any "middleware" has to do with the code in your post and your question about saving a user's navigation history in a middleware. What library/etc are you using that uses middleware that you need to create one to track a user's history? I was saying that whatever that library/etc is should/would typically include documentation for how to write a custom middleware function for any custom functionality.

You can create a JS function, and use Loader to call that function, which acts very similar like a Middleware.
Example:
//Inside the file path that have the loader.
export async function loader() {
  const info= await getInfo();
  return info;
}

You then create the logic (Fetching API or whatever) in separate folder.
export async function getInfo(id) {
  const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/info/${id}`);
  if (!res.ok) throw Error(`Couldn't find info#${id}`);

  const { data } = await res.json();
  return data;
}

You call the function in the loader, like a middleware. This is how you usually do it with react router. This is a basic implementation but hope it helps.

not. I need a middleware, which would have the previous url of the page and the one we are going to.
